# How to implement OpenID Connect with multiple providers in Django?

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid

I'm trying to implement multiple SSO (OpenID Connect) logins in my application, besides the regular one.

The current provider requests are Azure and Okta, but there will be more.
For every bigger customer using my application, I want to be able to enable them a custom SSO login that they can setup in the admin panel.

All the libraries I've tried using for this are either using settings.py and local django authentication, or they are deprecated.

The flow is like this:

User chooses their company and SSO login button -> Gets redirected to login -> I send the client id, secret etc. (which they entered in the admin panel when registering an sso connection) -> I get a token in return with the users name and email -> with this info (email) I find the already existing user in my local database and log him in

Answer (score 1):

Your own applications usually prefers to trust only **one** provider and when you want to involve multiple providers, the best way is to add your own OIDC provider locally, that your applications and API's trust. And then your OIDC provider can trust various other providers. Like how this picture below shows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes this is the structure I'm using.

But my question is specific on how to implement this, and which library to use in Django?

Comment: You need to choose an Identity provider solution, like https://github.com/IdentityPython/oidc-op https://duendesoftware.com/ https://www.keycloak.org/ https://documentation.openiddict.com/ , preferable a certified version, see this page for more ideas https://github.com/IdentityPython/oidc-op

Comment: Which one to choose all depends on your architecture and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem except that I needed support for multiple identity providers for SAML as well as OIDC, and solved it as follows.

- I noticed that the [django-social-auth](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) package SAML SSO implementation supports multiple "idp"s, based on configuration in settings.py.
- Based on that, the first step was to work up an abstraction in a Django model I called an `IdentityProvider` (glossing over the terminology differences between SAML and OIDC) and a pure-Python analogue called an `Idp` which is a thin wrapper around saml.SAMLIdentityProvider. So, in models.py:

  ```
  class IdentityProvider(models.Model):
      """
      SAML or OIDC Identity Provider for SSO. Based on the model exposed by
      PSA/python3-saml to multiple db-defined SSO setups.
      """
      ...
      real_backend = models.CharField("See below for what this is!!!!")
  ```

  and elsewhere:

  ```
  class IdP(saml.SAMLIdentityProvider):
      def get_display_name(self, lang):
         ...
         return display_name

      def get_logo(self):
         ...
         return logo
  ```
- The SAML backend was supplemented by a `MultiBackendMixin` to allow idps to be discovered either from configuration in settings.py or in `IdentityProvider` instances:

  ```
  class SAMLSandboxAuth(MultiBackendMixin, saml.SAMLAuth):
     ...
  ```

  and a similar one for OIDC:

  ```
  class OIDCSandboxAuth(MultiBackendMixin, base.BaseAuth):
     ...content based loosely on saml.SAMLAuth...
  ```

Conceptually, all SSO is done via these "SandboxAuths", and each defers to a "real" backend for the actual logic:

```
class SAMLAuth(saml.SAMLAuth):
   ...generic SAML backend...

class SAMLAuthMicrosoftAzureAD(SAMLAuth):
   ...Microsoft Azure AD SAML hacks for login_hint...
```

Notice that I've effectively used `saml.SAMLAuth` once as a SandboxAuth, and once as a "real" backend!!! The OIDC case is similar except that of course `OIDCSandboxAuth` is fully my own as above.

I should note that my flow is the same as your EXCEPT that the first step is for the user to provide their login name. I use that to look up the `IdentityProvider` (and thus display the name and logo) they need to use. The "real" backends provide this name as a login_hint where the other end supports it.

Answer (score 0):

1. > User chooses their company and SSO login button

OK, you can just simply put the buttons on your website.

2. > Gets redirected to login

You can imlpement `/redirect` endpoint and make sure do something to ready for getting user information from OAuth2 provider.

3. > I send the client id, secret etc. (which they entered in the admin panel when registering an sso connection)

This is also continue of step 2. but I don't know how to connect with Django admin panel. sorry.

4. > I get a token in return with the users name and email

Use OAuth2 provider's user info API. So you can get user's information whatever you want as much as they give.

5. > with this info (email) I find the already existing user in my local database and log him in

Just write a function with database. it is not hard.

I think that's enough to implement this.
but `that they can setup in the admin panel.`
I can't sure you can customize "already made" Django admin panel. That may be hard to do.